# PHP Save Remote Image From URL (SSL) - With A Quirk

Tags: php

SO,
I DID search! But I'm having an odd problem I didn't see addressed.

I have a SharePoint site using SSL that has images I'd like to download from my PHP page. I have valid credentials to authenticate with the SharePoint site (single sign on as well).

I'm able to directly navigate to the image file URL and it loads the image fine (and no authentication is asked for).

When I try any of the available file saving options in PHP, nothing works. Closest I've gotten is a jpg file is created with a size of 0KB.

I'm not understanding why it allows me to load the image in the browser navigating directly, but I can't get a script to download that image locally.

EDIT:

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}

$out = get_web_page("https://myfakeurl/65980014247151/65980014247151.jpg");

print_r($out);
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://myfakeurl/65980014247151/65980014247151.jpg
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 401
    [header_size] => 287
    [request_size] => 179
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 20
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.031
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.015
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.015
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.031
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [errno] => 0
    [errmsg] => 
    [content] => 
)
```

The 401 Unauthorized response makes me think it wants me to authenticate some how, but I don't know how. I guess loading the page directly in the browser works through Single Sign on, but that won't work with cURL.

Comment: perhaps [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126409/authenticate-to-sharepoint-online-office-365-with-curl) could help?

Comment: no dice. I didn't mention that I'm using Thybag's SharePointAPI to access the site and retrieve the image URL's from a Document Library List. This works perfect. I can even display the images on a page using the returned path. Where I'm stuck is I'm trying to write that HTML to a TCPDF script, and it apparently isn't able to retrieve the images either by using standard html path to img or with attempting to download the file locally first, then referencing it (which is what I am currently playing with).